# Keypress event for ajax call does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do the same event. "Click" to call the ajax, however now with keypress will put all the code and tell you where I think this error.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Call Ajax Click  <----- THIS WORK
    $('.container-list-podcast').on('click', '.link-podcast', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
    });

    // Call Ajax Key Enter  <----- THIS NOT WORK
    $('.container-list-podcast').on('keypress == 13', '.selected', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE AND COMPLETE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/10/)

Answer (score 3):

Your event hook is incorrect as you have to check the key pressed by interrogating the event which raised the `keypress`. Try this:

```
// Call Ajax Key Enter
$('.container-list-podcast').on('keypress', '.selected', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13) { // keyCode 13 == Enter key
        $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code actually makes sense, but could not the same action as the previous code, did not return ajax.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, as there is no AJAX involved in your example?

Comment: had no ajax call using keypress, click on works.
updated the fiddle to your code. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/11/)
Click with your mouse the item will work, enter does not work.